# How to setup vespa nodes for High availability

Tags: vespa

I have to deploy the Vespa database and the requirement is that it should be highly available. I have 3 instances available for the database. I have successfully deployed the database where 1 instance had config node, container node, and content node and the rest 2 instances had container node and config node.
Redundancy was kept as 3 and searchable copies are also 3.
But the issue here is if the instance with config node stops due to any reason then the whole system is unavailable.

So to avoid this, I was trying to have a config node on all the instances. But didn't able to deploy it successfully.

Link that I referred:
https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/services-admin.html

```
<admin version="2.0">
    <adminserver hostalias="admin0"/>
    <configservers>
        <configserver hostalias="admin0"/>
        <configserver hostalias="admin1"/>
        <configserver hostalias="admin2"/>
    </configservers>
</admin>
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Also, is there a better way to ensure availability in Vespa, Please do let me know?

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the documents are stored on the *content* nodes, so you need three of those, too. So maybe just set up config, container and content on all nodes?

Comment: Content nodes and container nodes are configured on all nodes. Apart from that, I want to have a config node on all the instances.

Comment: "But didn't able to deploy it successfully." Could you be more specific?

Comment: Note also that while it's good to have multiple config servers, the rest of the system does not go down if the config server goes down - it just means the system cannot change until it comes back up.

Comment: After deploying the application package. I checked for the system status using vespa-get-cluster-state and I get all the nodes are active. I was able to add, search and delete the records. But when I stopped one instance I was not able to add the records and the remaining data  from the stopped instance didn't get active in the running instances.

Comment: If the config node goes down, I am not able to query the database, add the record to the database. Which impact our API's that are using the database.

Comment: I think we need more info to get progress on this, I suggest you use https://vespa.ai/support to open a github issue where you can paste environment, output and logs. The cluster shall work fine with a node stopped, so there is something wrong